# Changing Language: globalization, culture depending on domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, globalization

I'm currently working on a MVC3 project where the globalization on a site is configured in the web.config.

I want to implement a functionality that changes the globalization to a different language depending on what domain your browsing from. So the globalization will change at run time depending on what site-address you browse from.

How can I acquire this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

**First, get the domain:**

You can use `Request.Uri.host` as referenced [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx), or even `Request.Uri.Scheme` as referenced [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.scheme.aspx).

**Then, change your culture settings:**

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("differentCultureHere");
```

[`CurrentCulture` reference.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The ideal solution would be a [re-write that included the use of `resources`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181738/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part) :) , but when life gives you lemons. . .